# Не знаю как сделать чтобы файл создавался там где я создаю папку

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловые-пути

```
import os

world=input()

os.mkdir(world)

test = open(f'{world}.txt', 'w')

test.write(world)
```

Хочу чтобы файл создавался там где я создаю папку и не понимаю как это зделать

Comment: Начни с чтения ошибки. Попробуй посмотреть на примеры использования команд, которые используеш. И исправь заголовок, чтобы он отражал твою проблему.

Comment: @Эникейщик

`world=input()

os.mkdir(world)

test = open(f'{world}.txt', 'w')

test.write(world)`
Надеюсь вы поймете что тут написано ибо я не знаю почему он не ставит пробелы
Как сделать чтобы в этом коде файл создавался в папке которую я создал?Если неправильно поставил вопрос скажите что вам непонятно был бы крайне благодарен

Comment: @Эникейщик Изменил и откорректировал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код:

```
world=input()

os.mkdir(world)
```

Значит, в переменной `world` вы ожидаете имя **папки** (или путь к папке).

```
test = open(f'{world}.txt', 'w')
```

Что будет `f'{world}.txt'`? Имя **папки**, точка, `txt`. Поняли?

Отсутствует имя **файла**.

Comment: Да, я исправил и добавил ещё к world и имя файла, я почему-то думал что это будет и именем файла и названия папки, всё заработало спасибо